# Unable to run flutter project due DART cache error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies, cache-control

Able to run other projects on the same device and also able to run the same project on a different device.

Below is the error.

Console Error

[image: console error]

Dart Packages Problem

[image: packageErr]

Tried multiple commands like dart pub cache clean, dart pub cache repair, and flutter upgrade
Even deleted the cache folder but the problem was still unsolved.

Comment: can you try upgrading the packages `flutter pub upgrade`

Comment: Tried that as well but no progress

Comment: can you try `firebase_auth_web: ^5.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the fork on GitHub and on the local machine. Then re-fork the branch and install the machine. Finally, delete the flutter folder and download it again. This worked for me